# Seaborn Heatmap Plotting Execution Time Optimization

Tags: numpy, optimization, time, heatmap, seaborn

I have a 4D numpy array, consider the 4th dimension to be the "time" dimension. Consecutive frames are being plotted as a 2D heatmap, using the first two dimensions - you are getting an "animation". When measuring the execution time, I am getting 16 seconds for 26 frames, which is pretty low. How can I speed up the execution time of the code below? I would prefer to use Seaborn to create the heatmaps, instead of matplotlib (even though it is an extension of the latter).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import time

data = np.load('data.npy')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = sns.heatmap(np.zeros((256, 128)), cmap = 'viridis', vmin = 0, vmax = 90)
plt.show(block = False)

start = time.time()
for i in range (0, data[0, 0, 0, :].size):
    plt.clf()
    sns.heatmap(20*np.log10(abs(data[:, :, 2, i])), cmap = 'viridis', vmin = 0, vmax = 90)
    fig.canvas.draw()
end = time.time()

print(end - start)
```

Comment: How about pre-compute : `20*np.log10(np.abs(data))` before going into the loop and use those inside the loop without the compute involved?

Comment: Good idea - it improved it by about 4 seconds - now 26 frames are displayed in 11.7 seconds. Some data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ksYqU-Jy7sRkczaVBLS3NuOUU

Comment: I need a framerate of about 12.5Hz - the overall display time for this dataset should be about 2-3 seconds.

Comment: You're going to need to drop down to matplotlib and use their [animation API](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html), i.e. doing things like pre-generating the mesh and then updating the data on each iteration and blitting the rest of the axes.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code, doing a similar task? By that I mean plotting a 2D numpy array as heatmap, as an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below produces exactly the same plot as seaborn, but 10 times faster (execution time = about 2 seconds):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import time

data = np.load('data.npy')
data = 20*np.log10(abs(data))

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#initialise subfigure (dimensions and parameters)
im = ax.imshow(np.zeros((256, 128)), cmap = 'viridis', vmin = 0, vmax = 90, interpolation = 'none', aspect = 'auto')

#get rid of spines and fix range of axes, rotate x-axis labels
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 128, 5))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 256, 10))
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)

#use a divider to fix the size of the colorbar
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
#colorbar on the right of ax. Colorbar width in % of ax and space between them is defined by pad in inches
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size = '5%', pad = 0.07) 
cb = fig.colorbar(im, cax = cax)
#remove colorbar frame/spines
cb.outline.set_visible(False)

#don't stop after each subfigure change
plt.show(block = False)

#loop through array
start = time.time()
for i in range(data[0, 0, 2, :].size):
    time.sleep(0.005)
    im.set_array(data[:, :, 0, i])  
    fig.canvas.draw()
stop = time.time()
print(stop-start)
```